# Reverse lookup in CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to select `img` tags which do not wrap under `table`. The code below should return only 1 as length as this HTML only has 1 `img` tag not under a `table`.

**Note :** Changing the markup/style isn't possible.

```js
console.log(document.querySelectorAll('img').length)
```

```html
<table align="center">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="text-align: center;">
        <a href="https://xxx" imageanchor="1" style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
          <img border="0" src="https://xxx" original="https://xxx" style="">
        </a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="tr-caption" style="text-align: center;">Double Trailing</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<a href="https://xxx" imageanchor="1" style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
  <img border="0" src="https://xxx" original="https://yyy" style="">
</a>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To target elements that **don't** satisfy a given criteria, you can use the [`:not()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) pseudo class in CSS:

```js
console.log(document.querySelectorAll('img:not(table img)').length)
```

```html
<table align="center">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="text-align: center;">
        <a href="https://xxx" imageanchor="1" style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
          <img border="0" src="https://xxx" original="https://xxx" style="">
        </a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="tr-caption" style="text-align: center;">Double Trailing</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<a href="https://xxx" imageanchor="1" style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
  <img border="0" src="https://xxx" original="https://yyy" style="">
</a>
```

> Can you please explain why this img:not(table) does not work?

`img:not(table)` selects all img elements that are not table elements.

`img:not(table img)` selects all img elements who are not img elements that are descendants of table elements.

In other words, anything inside `:not()` you can kinda think of as global scope, it doesn't know what's before/after it, so pretend you're applying it on the `*` universal selector wherever you use it.

Comment: What an elegant answer, and great to know.

Comment: @ConnerWithAnE It came up that you tried to propose an edit but I'd edited so it conflicted, what were you trying to add?

Comment: Oh I was simply trying to make the text a regular size, remove the ------- part so that the font size is normal. Just so it looks more uniform.

Comment: Oh I see, stylistic preference 

Comment: @ZachJensz Thanks a ton. Can you please explain why this img:not(table) does not work?

Comment: @UjjawalBhandari Hopefully my edit will help you understand better